# configuration jdk in android studio with ubuntu 17.10 not found java home

Tags: android, android-studio, configuration, java-8, ubuntu-16.04

When I open Android studio, I am getting the following error:

```
java_home not found
```

My configuration :

Android Studio 3.0
Ubuntu 17.10 Gnome
java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)

I ran: `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default`
(and installed to /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/)
I edited "/etc/environment" and set `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/"`
And added the following lines to "/home/faiberts/.bashrc" and "/root/.bashrc":

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Do I have some error in some step or it is necessary to change some configuration because I am confused since this is my first time trying to do development in android.

Thank you in advance for your valuable help.

Comment: Did you `source .bashrc`?

Comment: @faiberts Whats the optput of ` echo $JAVA_HOME ` and ` echo $PATH` .